# Direct Buy Now button for a product in home page: Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a product in the Magento store that needs a "buy now" button to take the product directly into the checkout page without adding it to the cart.

I have tried this but nothing worked:

```
<button onclick="location.href ='{{config path="web/unsecure/base_url"}}/checkout/cart/add?product=1&qty=1′">Buy It Now</button>
```

Comment: As of Magento 1.8, you need to pass the form_key variable along too.  The best way to go here would be to build a module with your logic, and set the link to that module.

Comment: I am working with "Magento ver. 1.9.2.2"

Answer (score 1):

This is the Solution which i found:

**add a Buy now button on Product View page**

add the buy now button to addtoCart.phtml

```
 <button type="button" title="Buy Now" class="button btn-buy" onclick="productBuyNowForm.submit(this)"><?php echo $this->__('Buy Now'); ?> </button>
```

On that buttons onlick event, a custom VarienForm is used, productBuyNowForm.submit(this), which will submit this form and redirect to checkout onepage.

add the following JavaScript code at view.phtml

```
var productBuyNowForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
productBuyNowForm.submit = function (button, url) {

if(!document.getElementsByName("return_url")){
   var element = document.getElementById("product_addtocart_form");
   var child=document.getElementById("return_url");
   element.removeChild(child);
 } 

if (this.validator.validate()) {
    var form = this.form;
    var oldUrl = form.action;
    if (url) {
        form.action = url;
    }

    var inputreturn= document.createElement("input");
    inputreturn.type = "hidden";
    inputreturn.name = "return_url";
    inputreturn.value = "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage')?>";
          document.getElementById('product_addtocart_form').appendChild(inputreturn);


    // Append a line break 
    var e = null;
    try {
        this.form.submit();
    } catch (e) {
    }
    this.form.action = oldUrl;
    if (e) {
        throw e;
    }

    if (button && button != 'undefined') {
        button.disabled = true;
    }
  }
}.bind(productBuyNowForm);
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked.
When clicking the Buy Now button, the item enters the basket and is directed to the Shopping Cart or Checkout page (can be setup via `<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart')?>`)
but the Add To Cart button is directed to the Shopping Cart too.
I want the Add To Cart button to remain like its function (the settings in the backend for After Adding a Product Redirect to Shopping Cart I have selected No) where the item is added to the basket but still on the same page

Answer (score 0):

Starting Magento 1.8 it's not possible anymore to add a product to the cart via an external referrer. All the add to cart actions depend on the user form key that is different from session to session.

If you can edit the template file, you can use php:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('checkout/cart')->getAddUrl($_product);?>
```